# Would it be possible to create a faux mouse click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation wherein I need to click on one element and then simultaneously trick the browser into receiving or thinking that another element also received a mouse click event.

jQuery pseudo code would be something like this:

```
$('a#someAnchor').click(function(){
    $('#someDiv').i_too_was_clicked();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, it's called [jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: `.trigger("click")` or just `.click()` with no arguments.